# Não Consigo Criar BitmapImage "interface that was marshalled for a different thread"

Tags: c#, wpf

Erro:

> System.Exception: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

Eu estou tentando obter um `BitmapImage` a partir de um `StorageItemThumbnail`, mas eu não consigo nem cria-lo, sempre que eu tento cria-lo `BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();`  recebo o erro acima independente se eu usar `Dispatcher.Invoke` ou não. Ele é a única linha que da o problema.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetThumbnailFile();
    }

    private async void GetThumbnailFile()
    {
        BitmapImage image  = await ThumbnailPhoto(@"C:\...\");

    }

    private async Task<BitmapImage> ThumbnailPhoto(string FilePath)
    {
        StorageFile sf = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(FilePath);
        StorageItemThumbnail fileThumbnail = await sf.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 250);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(fileThumbnail);

        return bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

Windows 10 API para usar StorageFile: [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#vZiZ96PlZUqTduts.97)

Não funcionam: [resolução1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705842/the-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-different-thread), [resolução2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/f1fe027f-2c6c-4a22-9418-566fcf67cebe/the-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-different-thread?forum=winappswithcsharp), `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

BitmapImage usado: `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

É necessário utilizar `BeginInit()`, `bitmap.EndInit()` e `bitmap.Freeze()`.

Exemplo:

```
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;                
bitmap.EndInit();
bitmap.Freeze();
```